# Opencl enabling register spilling option

Tags: java, recursion, opencl, gpu, raytracing

I converted a raytrace algortihm for C++ from [scratchapixel.com site](http://scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-1-writing-a-simple-raytracer/) into an opencl java(compiled for gpu) form and it doesnt work for depth values equal to or greater than 7. When I set depth to 7(or higher), compiler tells:

```
Error:E013:Insufficient Private Resources!
```

because of the semi-recursive functions that each one gets another copy of 32bit private registers(60+). **I need those registers to spill to main memory so I can set higher depth values without making the kernel into an iterative version. Is enabling spilling a bad idea? If not, how can I enable it?**

and if I set number of spheres to value bigger than 100ish values, compiler tells:

```
Frontend phase failed compilation.
Error: Creating kernel rayTraceSphereRender failed!
```

but total buffer number and buffer length are constant until sphereNumber=4096 so its only a change of "for loop bound" from 100 to 110 and compiler gives that error. I suspect it automatically unrolls loops and that makes bigger register pressure. This leads to higher private register needs again(and needs to be spilled again)

Here is how the kernel string is built by host:

```
kernelx+=

                 "float4 trace"+(depth+1)+"(float4 *rayorig, float4 *raydir,__global sphereObject *spheres, int sphereNum, int depth, int threadNo ){return (float4)(0,0,0,0);}";



        for(int iteration=depth;iteration>=0;iteration--)
        {
        //here is the bloating action to make traceX(...) function semi-recursive.
        kernelx+=   

                 "float4 trace"+iteration+"(float4 *rayorig, float4 *raydir,__global sphereObject *spheres, int sphereNum, int depth, int threadNo )"
                + "{"
                + "                   int MAX_RAY_DEPTH="+depth+";"
                        + "float facingratio =0; float fresneleffect=0;"
                        + "float4 refldir=(float4)(0,0,0,0);"
                        + "float4 arg00=(float4)(0,0,0,0);  float4 reflection=(float4)(0,0,0,0);float4 refraction=(float4)(0,0,0,0);"
                        + "float4 refrdir=(float4)(0,0,0,0); float4 arg01=(float4)(0,0,0,0);  "
                        + "float4 surfaceColor=(float4)(0,0,0,0);"
                        + "float4 phit=(float4)(0,0,0,0); "
                        + "float4 nhit=(float4)(0,0,0,0);"
                        + "float bias=0.000f;     "
                        + "float4 traceTmpReturn=(float4)(0,0,0,0);"
                        + "float tnear=100000000.0f;  "
                        + "sphereObject so;"
                + "                   initElem(&so);  "
                + "                   for(int i=0;i<sphereNum;i++)"
                + "                   {"
                + "                           float t0=100000000.0f;float t1=100000000.0f;"
                + "                           if(intersect(rayorig[0],raydir[0],&t0,&t1,spheres[i].center,spheres[i].radius)==1)" 
                + "                           {"
                + "                                  if(t0<0){t0=t1;}"
                + "                                  if(t0<tnear)"
                + "                                  {"
                + "                                        tnear=t0;"
                //+ "                                        so=&spheres[i];"
                + "                                        copyElem(&so,spheres[i]);"
                + "                                  }"  
                + "                           }"
                + "                    }"
                + "                      "
                + "                    if(so.radius<-0.5f){ return (float4)(0,0,0,0);} "
                + ""
                + "                    surfaceColor=(float4)(0,0,0,0);"
                + "                    phit=rayorig[0]+raydir[0]*tnear;"
                + "                    nhit=phit-so.center;"
                + "                    nhit=normalize(nhit);"
                + "                    bias=0.001f;"
                + "                    bool inside=false;"
                + "                    if(dot3X(raydir[0],nhit)>0){nhit=-nhit; inside=true;}"
                + "                    if(((so.transparency > 0) || (so.reflection > 0))&& (depth<MAX_RAY_DEPTH) )"
                + "                    {"
                + "                         facingratio = -dot3X(raydir[0],nhit);"
                + "                         fresneleffect= mixx(pow(1.0f-facingratio,3),1.0f,0.1f);"
                + "                         refldir = raydir[0] - nhit*2.0f*dot3X(raydir[0],nhit);"
                + "                         refldir=normalize(refldir);"
                + "                         arg00=phit+nhit*bias;"
                + "                         reflection=trace"+(iteration+1)+"(&arg00,&refldir,spheres,sphereNum,depth+1,threadNo);"
                + "                         refraction=(float4)(0,0,0,0);"
                + "                         if(so.transparency>0)"
                + "                         {"
                + "                               float ior=1.1f; float eta=(inside)?ior:1/ior; "
                + "                               float cosi=-dot3X(nhit,raydir[0]);"
                + "                               float k=1.0f-eta*eta*(1.0f-cosi*cosi);"
                + "                               refrdir = raydir[0]*eta+nhit*(eta*cosi-sqrt(k));"
                + "                               refrdir=normalize(refrdir);"
                + "                               arg01=phit-nhit*bias;"
                + "                               refraction=trace"+(iteration+1)+"(&arg01,&refrdir, spheres,sphereNum, depth+1, threadNo);"
                + "                                "
                + "                         }"
                + "                         surfaceColor=(reflection*fresneleffect+refraction*(1.0f-fresneleffect)*so.transparency)*so.surfaceColor;"
                + ""
                + "                    }"
                + "                    else"
                + "                    {"
                + "                         for(int i=0;i<sphereNum;i++)"
                + "                         {"
                + "                                if(spheres[i].emissionColor.x>0)"
                + "                                {"
                + "                                      float4 transmission=(float4)(1,1,1,1);"
                + "                                      float4 lightDirection=spheres[i].center-phit;"
                + "                                      lightDirection=normalize(lightDirection);"
                + "                                      for(int j=0;j<sphereNum;j++)"
                + "                                      {"
                + "                                            if(i!=j)"
                + "                                            {"
                + "                                                float t0,t1;"
                + "                                                float4 arg02=phit+nhit*bias;"
                + "                                                if(intersect(arg02,lightDirection,&t0,&t1,spheres[j].center,spheres[j].radius)==1)"
                + "                                                {"
                + "                                                      transmission= (float4)(0,0,0,0);break;"
                + "                                                } "
                + "                                            } "
                + "                                      }"
                + "                                      surfaceColor += so.surfaceColor*transmission*max(0.0f, dot3X(nhit,lightDirection))*spheres[i].emissionColor;"

                + "                                 }"
                + "                         }"
                + "                    }"
                + ""
                + "                    return surfaceColor+so.emissionColor;  "

                + "}";
        }






        kernelx+= "__kernel void rayTraceSphereRender(__global float4 *center, __global float *radius,"
        + "                                      __global float4 *surfaceColor, __global float4 *emissionColor,"
        + "                                      __global float *transparency,"
        + "                                      __global float *reflection, __global float4 *image,"
        + "                                      __global sphereObject *spheres)"+
        "{"+
        "    int gid=get_global_id(0);" +
        "    int lid=get_local_id(0);"
        + "  "
        + "  {"
        + "        int numSphr="+raytraceSphereNumber0+";"
        + "        int width="+n+", height="+n+";"
        + "        float invWidth = 1.0f/((float)width);"
        + "        float invHeight= 1.0f/((float)height);"
        + "        float fov = 30.0f; float aspectratio= ((float)width)/((float)height);"
        + "        float angle=tan(3.141592653589793f*0.5f*fov/(180.0f));"
        + "        int y=gid/"+n+";"
        + "        "
        + "        int x=gid%"+n+";"
        + "        "

        + "                     float xx=(2.0f*((x-0.5f)*invWidth)-1.0f)*angle*aspectratio;"
        + "                     float yy=(1.0f-2.0f*((y-0.5f)*invHeight))*angle;"
        + "                     float4 raydir=(float4)(xx,yy,-1.0f,0.0f);"

        + "                     raydir=normalize(raydir);"
        + "                     float4 ref=(float4)(0,0,0,0);"
        + "                     float4 upp=(float4)(0,0,0,0);"
        + "                     upp=trace0(&ref,&raydir,spheres,numSphr,0,gid);"
        + "                     upp.w=1.0;"
        + "              if(x>(width-width/"+sayi2+"))   image[y+x*"+n+"]=upp;"

        + "                      "
        + "         "
        + "        "
        + "  }"
        + "  "
         //   


        +"}";
```

Host: FX8150 windows7-64bit home premium,  Java-64bit(Eclipse)

Device: HD7870 Catalyst 13.12

Code works fine for lower depth and sphere numbers for GPU; and no problem for CPU for whatever number of depth and sphere I set:

[image]

Comment: Private memory can spill to local, and up to global in some cases. But that depends on the device, you shouldn't expect it to happen for limit cases. Have you tried other compiler of platform? Maybe a new version of the OpenCL compiler helps with this issue

Comment: Im using latest jocl libraries but they may be old. Setting up a custom JNI-based(using latest Khronos cl 1.2 C++ bindings) can get more time than making this raytracer an iterative version :D Im sure next version of jocl will be better but I dont know when. CPU compiler works ok for now. But at least 3x to 20x slower with different depth settings.

Comment: If you are asking about drivers(are they compiling this?), Im for Catalyst 13.12 so no new drivers yet.

Comment: The kernel code goes eventually to the driver in the raw text form, and it's subsequently compiled by the driver itself. So a new Catalyst might help a bit.

Comment: I wish they put opencl 2.0 in that driver so recursivity is fully fixed.